# Apache Airflow 2.5.2, DAG is not getting triggered automatically

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Trying to run the below example DAG in Airflow 2.5.2.
We were using Airflow 1.10.14 previously & DAGs were running as expected, But in Airflow 2.5.2, DAGs are not scheduled, Manual trigger is working fine.
We are using **Kubernetes executor**.

I see this on logs
`{kubernetes_executor.py:494} INFO - Found 0 queued task instances`

Can someone help if there is any configuration change that we need to make.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
   
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

with DAG(
    "migration_test",
    default_args={
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    },

    description="Migration test",
    schedule='*/3 * * * *',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 4, 30),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["common"],
) as dag:

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="print_date",
        bash_command="date",
    )

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="sleep",
        depends_on_past=False,
        bash_command="sleep 5",
        retries=3,
    )


t1 >> t2
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible solution for this.

1). Change the catchup parameter to True in the DAG constructor:

```py
with DAG(
    "migration_test",
    default_args={
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "retries": 1,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    },
    description="Migration test",
    schedule_interval='*/3 * * * *',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 4, 30),
    catchup=True,  # Change this line to True
    tags=["common"],
) as dag:
```

2). You can update the Airflow configuration file (airflow.cfg) to enable catch-up behavior globally. Set catchup_by_default = True in the [scheduler] section of the configuration file. After updating the configuration, restart your Airflow services to apply the changes.

Let me know which works for you, All the best.

Comment: If we make catchup=True, it triggers all pending DAG runs right? How would that help?